# Icons appear as blocks (windows 8)

Tags: windows, windows-8, icons

**Some** windows 8 icons just got corrupted (i have no idea how) and now appear as blocks.
Many icons work fine... many don't

[image: this is what the icons look like now]

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What have you tried already?  Have you tried a reboot?  How about a [System Restore](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-8-system-restore-guide/)?

Comment: Reboot doesn't help. I don't want to perform a system restore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very likely that the cause of the problem is Segoe UI Symbol font that got corrupted for some reason.

Just get the font from somewhere (from [here](http://www.eightforums.com/attachments/f1/f2/15254d1358852579-missing-icons-seguisym.rar), for example), re-install it, and perhaps restart Windows.