# How to change icons For MSOffice applications in Windows 7/8 Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, microsoft-office, icons

**Update:** This is NOT for fixing corrupt icons - this is for changing icons, corrupt or not.

Original queston

This is NOT for the library icon nor for the Metro icons. This is for Windows 8 Explorer icons.

I'm able to change the default program from control panel or right click file in Explorer => properties. But I can't see a way to change the icon itself. I'm putting a screenshot of what I'm presented - the same holds true for PDF files or any other files.

[image]

**Edit:** Even when I try to change the icons of shortcuts, I'm unable to do so. Weird!

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: For starters, you can't change special shortcut icons, like those in Microsoft Office. Secondly, you'll have to play around with the extensions in the Registry, which is not supported by Microsoft.

Comment: @RandolphWest: What is your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new shortcut from the original MSOffice .exe file, and then you can change it's icon.  This works in `Windows 7` or `Windows 8`.

.
To create one, search the

> program files(x86)\office 14(or 15)\

or

> program files\Office 14(or 15)\

for the exe you want, and then right-click drag the .exe somewhere like **desktop** where you can create a shortcut.  You can then change the icon.

Win8:

[image]

Win7:

[image]

Win7:

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Microsoft Office* → *Microsoft Office Tools* → *Microsoft Office Picture Manager* → *Help* → *Detect and Repair*.

Check *Restore my shortcuts while repairing*.

This should restore all the Microsoft Office shortcuts and icons.